# handle disconnected TCP client

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, client, client-server, c#-3.0

i have 3 days working with handling a disconnected client that when i disconnect a client it keeps sending nothing and when i connect it again it have another id . `
public class SocketServer : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{

```
    internal const int MAX_CLIENTS = 10;
    public AsyncCallback pfnWorkerCallBack;
    private Socket m_mainSocket;
    private Socket[] m_workerSocket = new Socket[30];// Hard limit of 30 TOTAL CONNECTIONS!!

    private int m_clientCount = 0;
    public SocketServer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Display the local IP address on the GUI
        textBoxIP.Text = GetIP();
    }

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Run(new SocketServer());
    }
```

}`

```
internal void ButtonStartListenClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Check the port value
            if (textBoxPort.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Port Number");
                return;
            }
            string portStr = textBoxPort.Text;
            int port = System.Convert.ToInt32(portStr);
            // Create the listening socket...
            m_mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                      SocketType.Stream,
                                      ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
            // Bind to local IP Address...
            m_mainSocket.Bind(ipLocal);
            // Start listening...
            m_mainSocket.Listen(20);
            // Create the call back for any client connections...
            m_mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);

            UpdateControls(true);

        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The UpdateControls
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listening">The listening<see cref="bool"/></param>
    private void UpdateControls(bool listening)
    {
        buttonStartListen.Enabled = !listening;
        buttonStopListen.Enabled = listening;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The OnClientConnect
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="asyn">The asyn<see cref="IAsyncResult"/></param>
    public void OnClientConnect(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        try
        {
            // Here we complete/end the BeginAccept() asynchronous call
            // by calling EndAccept() - which returns the reference to
            // a new Socket object
            m_workerSocket[m_clientCount] = m_mainSocket.EndAccept(asyn);

            // Display this client connection as a status message on the GUI    
            String str = String.Format("Client # {0} connected", m_clientCount);
            SetFormStatus(str);
            LogIncomingMessageToForm(str);
            if (broadcastIncomingMessages)
            {
                SendMsgToAll(str);
            }

            // Send the client their ID (First thing the server sends!)
            //byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(m_clientCount.ToString());
            //Console.WriteLine(byData);
            //m_workerSocket[m_clientCount].Send(byData);
            Invoke(new Action(() => checkedListBox1.Items.Add("client " + (m_clientCount).ToString() + " => " + m_workerSocket[m_clientCount].RemoteEndPoint.ToString(), CheckState.Unchecked)));
            // Let the worker Socket do the further processing for the 
            // just connected client
            WaitForData(m_clientCount);

            // Now increment the client count
            ++m_clientCount;
            
            // Since the main Socket is now free, it can go back and wait for
            // other clients who are attempting to connect
            m_mainSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnClientConnect), null);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\n OnClientConnection: Socket has been closed\n");
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the <see cref="SocketPacket" />
    /// </summary>
    public class SocketPacket
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Defines the m_currentSocket
        /// </summary>
        public System.Net.Sockets.Socket m_currentSocket;

        /// <summary>
        /// Defines the dataBuffer
        /// </summary>
        public byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[255];

        /// <summary>
        /// Defines the id
        /// </summary>
        public int id;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The WaitForData
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The id<see cref="int"/></param>
    public void WaitForData(int id)
    {
        Socket soc = m_workerSocket[id];
        
        try
        {
            if (pfnWorkerCallBack == null)
            {
                // Specify the call back function which is to be 
                // invoked when there is any write activity by the 
                // connected client
                pfnWorkerCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
            }
            SocketPacket theSocPkt = new SocketPacket();
            theSocPkt.m_currentSocket = soc;
            theSocPkt.id = id;
            // Start receiving any data written by the connected client
            // asynchronously
            soc.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer, 0,
                               theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length,
                               SocketFlags.None,
                               pfnWorkerCallBack,
                               theSocPkt);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
        
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The OnDataReceived
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="asyn">The asyn<see cref="IAsyncResult"/></param>
    public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        try
        {
            SocketPacket socketData = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;

            int iRx = 0;
            // Complete the BeginReceive() asynchronous call by EndReceive() method
            // which will return the number of characters written to the stream 
            // by the client
            iRx = socketData.m_currentSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
            char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
            System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            int charLen = d.GetChars(socketData.dataBuffer,
                                     0, iRx, chars, 0);
            System.String szData = new System.String(chars);
            LogIncomingMessageToForm(socketData.id.ToString(), szData);
            if (broadcastIncomingMessages)
            {
                SendMsgToAll(socketData.id.ToString(), szData);
            }

            // Continue the waiting for data on the Socket
            WaitForData(socketData.id);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\nOnDataReceived: Socket has been closed\n");
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }
    }
```

then here i need to handle the disconnected client not to do that

[image]

Comment: One Listener can handle multiple client connections.  You only need to start the listener once.  The Accept method gets a new socket for each connection.  So in the asynchronous accept method you add the socket to your m_workerSocket[] array.  When you disconnect you remove the socket from the array.  So it is best to use a List<socket> instead of an array.

Comment: @jdweng it's not clear for me how should i check whether that socket is disconnected or still connected

Comment: What I normally do in the accept method is to get the socket remote end point (the IP address) and create a dictionary of dict<"ip", socket>.  Then you can test if IP is in dictionary.